# OpenSSL kill itself on certificate validation error

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

In OpenSSL I'm trying to check the certificate chain during the handshake.
When the client connects I create che `SSL_CTX*` and `SSL*` then I set up the verification callback

```
SSL_set_verify(_ssl, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, verify_callback);
```

And then in the function I have

```
int verify_callback(int preverify_ok, X509_STORE_CTX *x509_ctx) {
    bool ok = false;
    [...]
    return ok ? 1 : 0;
}
```

(I copied the code from the example in GitHub)
When I execute it, if the function returns 1, everything is ok but when it returns 0 (aka fail) the entire process halts (exit code 0)

I'm currently compiling under cygwin64 on Win10 x64, which are up to date

What's wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Also se [TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki. The sample code has a callback that prints the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has the answer:

> The return value of verify_callback controls the strategy of the further verification process. If verify_callback returns 0, the verification process is immediately stopped with "verification failed" state. If SSL_VERIFY_PEER is set, a verification failure alert is sent to the peer and the TLS/SSL handshake is terminated.

Taken from:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html

So maybe you're missing an exception or something.

Comment: The documentation doesn't talk about something like kill the process. I attach you what the program writes in stdout/stderr (taken from Netbeans output window) `4294956672:error:14089086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_certificate:certificate verify failed:s3_srvr.c:3270:`

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger? Also check for any thrown exceptions.

Comment: Ops...I thought I had written some code inside a try...catch statement, but actually not. My mistake! Thank you very much anyway